# Pwa APK doesn't go full screen

Tags: javascript, android, html, progressive-web-apps, manifest

Yesterday I made [my website](https://sky-music.herokuapp.com/) a PWA by adding the manifest and service worker, I did it mainly to add caching and offline support since it can be used 99% without an internet connection but then I found out about the possibility to turn a PWA into an APK that you can put on Google play.

So I added to the manifest this:

```
scope:"https://sky-music.herokuapp.com/",
display:"fullscreen"
```

but when I convert the pwa to APK and install it, the page is not full screen but shows the address bar on top, you can see what I mean in [this picture](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/407326714356826112/730795701415575673/Screenshot_20200709-163838.jpg), how can I solve it and make the app be full screen?

I've read around and I think the problem is in the scope, reading the documentation shows that by adding the URL of the website it would work with all the site but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it, I used the wrong file name for the well-known

It's supposed to be called .well-known , not well-known

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/android/trusted-web-activity/quick-start#creating-your-asset-link-file